# How to login to wordpress via Cpanel

Tags: login, wp-login-form

So I am 90% done with my website, I did a mistake with shortcode and removed the login option, now I cant login :(.
I tried website/login but the admin login option doesn't appear.

Any other way to trigger the login option.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress login page exist in yoursite.com/wp-login
If it doesn't exist download wp-login.php (you can google for it) and login to your cpanel via yoursite.com/cpanel and locate public_html/ folder or the folder where you install wordpress to and upload it.

Comment: **Don't just grab any `wp-login.php` file you find in Google.** Download the WordPress installation zipfile from https://wordpress.org/download/, unzip it locally, and upload the `wp-login.php` file from there to your server. (If you're not running the current WordPress version—4.9.5 as I type this—you might need to download an earlier version. Only download this from the official wordpress.org site.)